# "With" or "By" or "of" or "from"

Tags: prepositions

> Do you get bored *with* licking ice-cream?

or

> Do you get bored *by* licking ice-cream?

or

> Do you get bored *of* licking ice-cream?

or

> Do you get bored *from* licking ice-cream?

Comment: None of the above; licking ice-cream never gets boring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a property of the particular word *bored*, and seems to be in the process of changing.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bored+with%2Cbored+of%2Cbored+from&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbored%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbored%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbored%20from%3B%2Cc0) shows that *bored with* is overwhelmingly the most common, but that *bored of* has been on the rise since the 1990s.

Comment: Could you give me a general idea how to use these prepositions on specific occasions

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid, @Manishkumar. All the prepositions have their own core meanings, which are relevant when you are adding them as an optional adjunct (eg _I went to the shops_ vs _I went to the shops **with** my friend_). But when they are used to express part of the meaning of a word, you just have to learn which particular preposition (or none) the particular word takes.

Comment: It seems "bored at" is above "bored from",  and recently has overtaken "bored of"

Comment: He kept the glass at the same temperature as that of our stomach (can i use on instead of at)

Comment: @Manishkumar: _On_ doesn't sound natural to me. This is because _at [a temperature]_ is idiomatic, and _on [a temperature]_ isn't. Again, there is no rule or logic that will tell you this: it just happens to be the way the word 'temperature' is used.

Comment: Thank you- Colin Fine my new doubt is -"Three people were injured in the fire" (can i use on the fire in place of in the fire) in what circumstances we use "on fire",Is it used when burning takes place right now and for the situations in past we are bound to use"in fire"

Comment: @Manishkumar: again, we are in the realm of idiomatic (and unpredictable) use of prepositions. _On fire_ (without an article) means "burning, emitting flames". _In a/the fire_ means "physically in a fire, or damaged or hurt by a fire". _On a/the fire_ has several specific idiomatic meanings: cooking food on top of an open fire; adding fuel to a fire in a hearth; pouring something (eg water, foam, or kerosine) onto a fire. So _injured in the fire_ is idiomatic, but _in fire_ is not.

Comment: Could you prescribe me some source for good english

Comment: noun-variable - fire or a fire is an occurrence of uncontrolled burning which destroys buildings, forests, or other things.

Comment: Please explain me,its meaning regarding "injured in fire"

Comment: @Manishkumar: as I said above, _in fire_ is not idiomatic English. You might find it as part of phrases where 'fire' is a modifier, such as _in fire evacuation_; and you might find it in a headline or title (eg "three hurt in fire"); but not in normal English.

Comment: And (as I am neither a student nor a teacher of ESL) I have no particular knowledge of resources. I could google for them, but you could do so just as well.

Comment: I have a little knowledge of(in) english,I could not understand the meaning of idiomatic english,my intension was not to hurt you,

Comment: BBC NEWS-NRedcar SSI: (Headline)Two hurt in fire on former steelworks site.(Two people have been injured in a fire on a former steelworks site)

Comment: How many books had you given him vs how many books did you give him (what is a difference b/w in these two sentences)

Comment: @Manishkumar: that is a completely different question, and a comment here is not the right place to raise it. You should ask a new question - but first, go to the "English Language Learners" site, and search for "past perfect", and look through some of the 2508 previous questions about this. You will probably find some answers that are helpful

Comment: My car is at garage or my car is in garage (My car is at the garage.It is being repaired,somebody is repairing it ) I think there should be "in" instead of "at" because at present time it is  situated in the building/shed and is repaired and is not not  present outside the building/shed

Comment: I'm sorry, @Manishkumar, but I'm not going to engage with you any further on this question. If you have new questions, then please raise them as separate questions on ELL - but search first, to see if the question has already been answered.